# How to add fonts to a ComboBox in Avalonia?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, avaloniaui, avalonia

```
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
    x:Class="AvaloniaAppTemplate.MainWindow"
    Title="AvaloniaAppTemplate">
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox x:Name="fontComboBox"  SelectedIndex="0">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontFamily="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

code behind:

```
var fontComboBox = this.Find<ComboBox>("fontComboBox");
fontComboBox.Items = FontManager.Current.GetInstalledFontFamilyNames().Select(x => new FontFamily(x));
fontComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

This is the from the [documentation page](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/controls/combobox)

I am not able to make it work. It's quite different from initiating fonts on WPF, and I am stuck on this for some time now :(

Comment: I assume you're using Avalonia v0.10.x? With v11 there are a few changes you need to make, otherwise you'll get a couple error messages.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:

```
  <StackPanel>
    <ComboBox x:Name="fontComboBox">
      <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="FontFamily">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
  </StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        InstalledFontCollection installedFontCollection = new InstalledFontCollection();

        fontComboBox.ItemsSource = installedFontCollection.Families;
        fontComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```